# what is the best way to set author field on STI model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a basic model called Page and have many STI models based on Page such as

Drawing

Article

Story

etc...

I have separate controller and view for each of these STI models because I needed to customized the view layer based on the model type and have different logic for controller and hence separate controllers. However, I need the author field of all models to be set to current user. How do I do this in a single place?

For example, if I use before_action on Page controller and set the author, it affects the @page instance variable whereas my DrawingsController is using @drawing so it wont save the author of my @drawing unless I repeat the same code in DrawingsController.

**Edit:**

My controller hierarchy is

DrawingsController < PagesController

PagesController < ApplicationController

Both PagesController and DrawingsController have all the 7 restful actions. However, the actions on PagesController doesn't serve any purpose as I dont want any of my users to create Pages. I only want them to create the inherited STI classes like Drawings.

Comment: Given that the instance variables are of different names, I think you're only choice is to set the current user manually (or at least in each sub-controller). You "can" technically set the current user in a `before_save` in the model, assuming the current user is visible like that, but that would be a bad approach since responsibilities should remain as separate as possible. It might be beneficial to see your controller code as it is right now. Also, perhaps show us / describe your controller hierarchy too.

Comment: @Teeg added more info as per your comment. Adding users from model is mostly frowned upon as bad design as I read from various posts. So I'm not looking at that option.

Comment: Ok cool, so the controller structure is how I thought it was. I'm not certain what is generally considered best practice in this case. I do two similar solutions: #1 you create the model object in the sub controllers (drawing, for example) and pass it off to the parent (pages) to handle any "common" tasks, such as setting the author. Or, #2 you do the reverse: let the pages controller do 99% of the work, and create a protected method which the subcontrollers can implement to handle any model-specific things. I can post an answer if you'd like me to illustrate any of that.

Comment: @Teeg, thank you for your reply. Can you please post your answer for #1 and #2? I'm not clear about #2 particularly.

Comment: @Teeg, just wanted to check if you could post your answer when you are free.

Comment: Ack, sorry @krishworks, will do so shortly.

Answer (score 0):

you could do this using some convention and meta programming in your controller hierarchy:

```
def add_author
  model = instance_variable_get(:"@#{controller_name.singularize}")
  model.author = current_user
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, I make no guarantees about the "best-practice"-ness of this answer, but I'll propose it anyways in case it helps to some degree. Also note that after rethinking the problem, I realized my first suggested solution in the comments was wrong, and the second is also not quite right either. So I'm posting a modified version of the second suggestion only:

**Short answer:** Let the `PagesController` handle most of the work, and delegate only to the subcontroller for model-specific things if needed. As phoet said, you can use a bit of meta programming (in a different way) to accomplish this.

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    # pages controller stuff here
    def create
        @page = controller_name.classify.constantize.new(params[:page_params]) # I love Rails, don't you?
        @page.author = current_user
        handle_additional_create_actions 

        # For completeness of this example...
        if @page.save
            # render / redirect on success
        else
            # render errors
        end
    end
protected

    # This method should be overwritten by sub controllers if needed
    # Also, name this whatever you like, this is merely a verbose example for illustration purposes
    def handle_additional_create_actions
        # in the pages controller, this method does nothing
    end
end
```

And, if there are additional things that need to be done by the model-specific controller:

```
class DrawingsController < PagesController
    # drawing controller stuff here

protected
    def handle_additional_create_actions
        @page.some_other_field = some_other_data
    end
end
```

A quick note: Note that in my suggestion, you're eliminating the model-specific variable names, meaning we don't have an `@drawing` and an `@article`, etc, anymore. Your models are all, essentially, types of `Page` objects, and so we're going to call it by its general name as a convention. That way, when you ask the `DrawingsController` to do something specific for the `Drawing` class, it knows that instance can be accessed via our generically named `@page` object.

So ultimately, the `PagesController` does the heavy lifting, regardless of which concrete model type you're dealing with. That way, only general page stuff is found in the pages controller, and drawing, article or story-specific stuff is found in their respective concrete controllers.